# Best use of RAM for multiple SQL instances?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I have a new Windows Server 2016 box with 32GB of RAM, it will be used for dev testing by one or two users max. There will be occasional use of VM/Hyper-V instances and a couple of IIS test sites running from time to time.

I also need to install *all* versions of SQL Server from 2008 through to 2016. These will each have many databases attached but very few will actually be active at a time unless testing calls for it.

Assuming there is no practical issue with installing several different SQL Server installations on the same box, what options do I have to configure the best use of RAM? I know that on a standard installation, SQL will try to hog all available RAM but I want to try to avoid this leaving around 12GB for other services and allocate a maximum of 24GB for *all* the SQL instances to share equally without fighting with each other over resources.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

PS I'm not an experienced DBA just a humble developer

Comment: You said VM/Hyper-V, so we are talking about multiple Virtual machines with multiple SQL instance right? in this case big amount of calculations involved, as the maximum memory in answer below should not eat up windows server requirements on which SQL is installed. Else you IIS will not perform well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allocate maximum amounts of memory that each SQL Server instance can use through the [`sp_configure` stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx#Providing%20the%20Maximum%20Amount%20of%20Memory%20to%20SQL%20Server).  However, that won't be an absolute maximum, but a maximum amount of memory allocated to the storage of certain types of data, mainly data cached from the database.

If you're planning on running one instance of each version of SQL Server since 2008, you're looking at five instances of SQL Server on a 32MB server; you'll need to leave a few GB RAM available for the operating system and anything else on that server (SSIS?  SSRS?  SSAS?).  At a conservative estimate, you'll probably only have about 4GB RAM available for each instance, so you would run something like:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  -- ensure memory configuration option is available 
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
exec sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096; -- maximum memory in MB 
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Note that difference versions of SQL Server interpret the configuration setting in different ways - more recent versions apply the setting to more types of memory allocation.  There's a table about half way down this [sizing consideration document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2663912/memory-configuration-and-sizing-considerations-in-sql-server-2012-and-later-versions) that shows what's changed.

Comment: Since @userSteve will not be running all instances at the same time, the max memory for each instance can be increased to `total-mb-for-sql / number-of-concurrent-instances`.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping there might have been a setting during the installation wizard, but no matter  I'll give this a go and see what happens.

Comment: @DanGuzman What if I just install 32bit versions or Express versions of SQL, they will be naturally limited to a low amount of RAM, would that achieve the same thing?

Comment: @DanGuzman - if the instances are being shut down / fired up as necessary, then userSteve could have a separate process that monitors the number of running instances and then automates the (re-)configuration of max server memory (just in case someone forgets...)

Comment: 32-bit versions do have limits of the amount of memory they can use; as does SQL Express.  

However, SQLExpress also has other limits, which may bite you hard, particularly if you have larger databases.  And you definitely won't get the benefit of all that memory, as (eg) SQL2014Express is limited to 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue having many SQL instances, of the same or differing versions, on the same machine. My dev box has 2008r2, 2012 and 2016 (it also has 2005 still hanging around, but that is disabled currently as no longer supported by any of our products as it has passed EOL).

Separate instances will *not* cooperate on memory use though: they will all try claim as much as they need which is often all of it. If you do a lot of work in instance 1 and it claims most of your memory, then switch to testing something in instance 2, instance 2 has no way of requesting instance 1 release memory that is not actively being used to instance 2 will be relatively resource starved.

The only way to make them work equally is to give them a fixed maximum allocation, so for the five instances you have (assuming just the latest service packs of 2008, 2008r2, 2012, 2014 & 2016 - if you need separate instances for each SP level things get much more crowded!) to use up to 24Gb you would need to give them all a maximum (via server properties settings in SSMS or calls to `sp_configure`) of 4.8Gb.

Given the use cases you describe I suspect that this will be inefficient though: if the other instances are not in use then why limit the one you are using to 5Gb when it could have 24? If you know with reasonable certainty that instances will be used for the next day/hours/some-sensible-time-period then set them all to 24Gb maximum and restart (or completely stop) them to release memory as needed. This afternoon you are planning a testing session against: restart (or completely stop) the other instances to release their memory so it can claim what it needs (up to the 24Gb). Tomorrow morning's focus is 2012: same again. If in a given period your team(s) need to test on two instances, then for that time set those two instances to a maximum of 12Gb and reset/stop the others to release anything they are using.

Obviously the above is completely unsuitable for production, but it sounds like what you are setting up is a lab for devtest and QA work.

Another consideration is what parts of SQL Server you are using. In the above I've assumed engine only. If you are using SSAS, SSRS, or SSIS as well as the main SQL Server engine then the theory is similar but you have extra complications to deal with.

Comment: Some great advice there thanks @David.  Will not be using SSAS, SSRS, SSIS, only the standard query engine.  I think I'll just give it a go and see what happens, limiting each one to 4GB.    
Another reponse on a different site advised me to be cautious when using Hyper-V as this WILL require all resources, therefore I think I'll avoid that completely for this server.

Comment: What if I just install 32bit versions or Express versions of SQL, they will be naturally limited to a low amount of RAM, would that achieve the same thing?

Comment: Depending on your app using Express editions my cause breaks due to missing features, the max RAM is lower than 4Gb anyway, and performance metrics may differ (making it a bad representation of production for testing) due to the different resource governing rules. If you are licensed for standard/developer/enterprise editions then use them and limit the RAM, that way you can remove the limit easily and quickly if you need to. Also app dependent, but you might find 4Gb too small for realistic testing if the application is normally hosted on much more.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL 2019 in production with this setup - don't know if it applies to other version.

I have seen that differences instances does release memory as requested via the OS. When one instance requires more memory, and the OS does not have more to give, a "memory constraint" event will occur on OS level, which will request all programs (incl SQL) to release memory where possible.

This way (over simplified), you can have box with 16 GB Ram running 4 instances of SQL, and you allocate max 8 GB to each, and they will in turn release and request memory.

Note, this is not a fast action, the releasing of memory does occur over a few cycles.